# Embedding Java Applet in web page

Tags: java, html, applet, classnotfoundexception

I've built a java applet and am trying to embed it into an HTML file on my server. When I access the page, the applet tries to load but then crashes with a `ClassNotFoundException` on `.applet.BookingApplet.class` (which is the name of the applet, where `applet` is the name of the package the applet is in.)

```
   <body>
    <script src ="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script>
        var attributes = {
        codebase: '/webapp/HelpSessions.jar', 

       code: '/webapp/HelpSessions.jar/applet/BookingApplet.class',
       archive: '/lib/javax.persistence.jar, /lib/javax.validation-1.0.0.GA.jar, /lib/joda-time-2.1.jar, /lib/mail.jar, /lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar',
       width: 800, 
       height: 600        
        };
        var version = "1.6"
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, version);
        </script>
</body>
```

This is the first time I've tried to do anything like this, so I'm sure this is just a syntactical error with the way I'm referring to the class files in the HTML. I can post any other code if needed, but I don't think its relevant because the applet runs fine in AppletViewer.

I'm not going to sleep tonight till I get this thing running...

EDIT: To simplify things, I tried moving everything into one folder so I wouldn't have to deal with the codebase. Here's what it looks like now:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Schedule a Help Session</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script src ="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script>
        var attributes = {

       code: '/applet/BookingApplet.class',
       archive: '/lib/javax.persistence.jar, /lib/javax.validation-1.0.0.GA.jar, /lib/joda-time-2.1.jar, /lib/mail.jar, /lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar',
       width: 800, 
       height: 600        
        };
        var version = "1.6"
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, version);
        </script>
</body>
```

and I'm getting the same ClassNotFoundException. Also, I can see an InterruptedException in the details on the java console, but it doesn't tell me where (if anywhere) in my code the exception is being caused.

Comment: try to put the full path

Comment: put it where? Also, do you mean to include `public_html/`, because that's the only parent folder on the server

Comment: like C:/..., it might work, i am not sure

Comment: `code` is relative to `codebase`, so "applet/BookingApplet.class" might work there.

Comment: @btevfik - it's on a server, there is no c:/

Comment: did you try the applet tag? http://www.echoecho.com/applets01.htm

Comment: @Pietu1998 - that was the first way I was trying it, with the same result

Comment: @drewmore4 By the way, `archive` is also relative.

Comment: Also, is the applet in a folder like www.yourwebsite.com/webapp/HelpSessions.jar ?

Comment: yep, exactly. its in www.mywebsite/webapp/HelpSessions.jar.

Comment: What is the path (URL) to the HTML shown?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: http://laneycodingclub.com/newhtml.html

Comment: I guess Java is trying to convert '/' to '.', so "/applet/BookingApplet.class" becomes ".applet.BookingApplet". Maybe try changing the `code` attribute to "applet/BookingApplet.class"?

Comment: What Jar is `BookingApplet.class` located in?  Does it declare a package of `applet`?  Be sure to add @btevfik (or whoever) to notify them of a new comment.

Comment: @Pietu1998: Bingo. That did the trick. Add that comment as a question and I'll happily accept it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: solved

Comment: OK. Now just remember to set `codebase` to be the path to the parent folder of "applet".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `code` attribute to be "applet/BookingApplet.class". Currently you are using "/applet/BookingApplet.class".

When Java reads a URL, it converts any '/':s to '.':s. That will make the URL "/applet/BookingApplet.class" ".applet.BookingApplet.class". "applet/BookingApplet.class" will become "applet.BookingApplet.class", which is the correct one.

Just remember to set `codebase` to point to the directory where the "applet" directory is located.